# How to fix row reference in R

Tags: r, performance, reference, row, mean

I need to calculate the mean for payments occurred in last 180 days from each issue_date by customer. Using loop 'for' it takes a lot of time in my full dataset (570.000 rows). 
I try others functions, but always result of a mean for de full column of the dataset. I don´t know how to fix a row reference to get all payments occurred before de issue_date by each row.

See the dataset and the for function that I using.
Thanks in advance.

Dataset:

```
'ds<-data.frame(
  issue_date=as.Date(c("2018-03-17","2018-03-17","2018-03-17","2018-06-21","2018-06-21",
               "2019-10-03","2019-10-03","2019-03-02","2018-08-22","2018-06-21",
               "2018-08-22","2019-03-02","2019-06-08","2018-08-22","2018-12-11",
               "2019-03-02","2019-06-08","2018-12-11","2018-12-11","2017-12-13",
               "2017-12-13","2017-12-13","2018-04-19","2018-08-21","2019-01-09",
               "2019-07-24","2019-07-24","2019-10-10","2019-05-14")),
  due_date=as.Date(c("2018-04-14","2018-06-09","2018-05-12","2018-07-19","2018-09-13",
             "2019-10-31","2019-11-28","2019-05-25","2018-10-17","2018-08-16",
             "2018-09-19","2019-04-27","2019-07-06","2018-11-14","2019-02-05",
             "2019-03-30","2019-08-03","2019-03-05","2019-01-08","2018-01-10",
             "2018-03-07","2018-02-07","2018-05-03","2018-09-04","2019-01-29",
             "2019-09-11","2019-08-28","2019-10-30","2019-06-01")),
  customer=c(59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,
                          59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,
                          59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,
                          59570867,59570867,59570867,59570867,13389815,13389815,
                          13389815,13389815,13389815,13389815,13389815),
  late_payment=c(2,1,4,2,3,1,2,5,8,3,2,4,3,2,6,5,2,1,3,5,2,1,3,4,5,1,4,2,2)
)'
```

Loop 'for' to get the mean:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(ds)){
  ds$mean_180days[i]<-mean(ds[ds$customer==ds$customer[i] &
                          ds$due_date>=(ds$issue_date[i]-180) &
                          ds$due_date<(ds$issue_date[i]),"late_payment"])
  }
```

Result wiht a new column:

```
   issue_date   due_date customer late_payment mean_180days
1  2018-03-17 2018-04-14 59570867            2     2.666667
2  2018-03-17 2018-06-09 59570867            1     2.666667
3  2018-03-17 2018-05-12 59570867            4     2.666667
4  2018-06-21 2018-07-19 59570867            2     2.500000
5  2018-06-21 2018-09-13 59570867            3     2.500000
6  2019-10-03 2019-10-31 59570867            1     3.500000
7  2019-10-03 2019-11-28 59570867            2     3.500000
8  2019-03-02 2019-05-25 59570867            5     4.000000
9  2018-08-22 2018-10-17 59570867            8     2.333333
10 2018-06-21 2018-08-16 59570867            3     2.500000
11 2018-08-22 2018-09-19 59570867            2     2.333333
12 2019-03-02 2019-04-27 59570867            4     4.000000
13 2019-06-08 2019-07-06 59570867            3     4.000000
14 2018-08-22 2018-11-14 59570867            2     2.333333
15 2018-12-11 2019-02-05 59570867            6     3.333333
16 2019-03-02 2019-03-30 59570867            5     4.000000
17 2019-06-08 2019-08-03 59570867            2     4.000000
18 2018-12-11 2019-03-05 59570867            1     3.333333
19 2018-12-11 2019-01-08 59570867            3     3.333333
20 2017-12-13 2018-01-10 59570867            5          NaN
21 2017-12-13 2018-03-07 59570867            2          NaN
22 2017-12-13 2018-02-07 59570867            1          NaN
23 2018-04-19 2018-05-03 13389815            3          NaN
24 2018-08-21 2018-09-04 13389815            4     3.000000
25 2019-01-09 2019-01-29 13389815            5     4.000000
26 2019-07-24 2019-09-11 13389815            1     3.500000
27 2019-07-24 2019-08-28 13389815            4     3.500000
28 2019-10-10 2019-10-30 13389815            2     2.333333
29 2019-05-14 2019-06-01 13389815            2     5.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data is not quite in a format that allows this analysis to be done easily. However, I came up with a work-around that allows you to do what you intend. I'll present the solution here and discuss the different operations briefly afterwards.

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(customer, issue_date, due_date) %>% 
  arrange(due_date) %>% 
  group_by(due_date) %>%
  tidyr::fill(late_payment, .direction = "down") %>% 
  filter(due_date >= issue_date - 180 & due_date < issue_date) %>% 
  group_by(customer, issue_date) %>% 
  summarise(mean(late_payment))
```

- First we group the data per customer, such that we can create all possible combinations for that customer of `issue_date` and `due_date`. Please be aware that this step might be computationally expensive.
- We then re-sort these combinations according to the `due_date`. You can perform each step of the pipeline individually to study its effects on the sample you provided.
- Once sorted, the `late_payment` can be filled in using the first non `NA` value found per `due_date` (hence the grouping by also). i.e. the `late_payment` for the `issue_date / due_date` combinations found in your original data.
- We now filter out only those `late_payment` that occurred within 180 days from the issue_date.
- Finally, we can group_by `customer` and `issue date` to calculate the average.

Comment: Jeroen, thanks for you contribution. My correct question is more a kind of: Whats the payments "average" for last 180days?

Comment: I tested your suggestion, but it resulted in "NaN" like happened with 'aggregated'  I tried.

Comment: That is because your data (al least the sample provided above) does not contain late payments which occur (i.e. have a due date) within 180 days prior to the issue date. I seem to be missing some of the logic? Can you rephrase the goal your analysis?

Comment: thanks again for your return. I trying to prevent financial default by using a predictive machine learning model. The average for "late payments" is one of de attributes for the predictive model. In the sample above, row 27, issue_date 2019-10-10 , there were 3 payments in last 180 days for this customer (2019-09-11 , 2019-08-28, 2019-06-01), which late payments 1,4 and 2 days, so average of 2,33 days.
 I get the result using a code with loop "for" (above), but it takes a lot of time in processing (3,5 hours for this 570.000 rows of information).

Comment: The alternative solution I did, I divided the dataset in twelve subsets and process one after one. This way, it takes the total of 25 minutes to process all this twelve subsets (about 2 minutes for each) .
Maybe the first question is: Why is it takes 3,5 hours to process the full dataset, all the 570.000 rows? Its seems to be a exponential effect in processing time as more data is added.

Comment: It is now more clear for me what you wanted to do. The `dplyr/tidyr` pipeline I presented in the solution should be much more efficient than running for loops. The `complete` step might still take quite a time: it finds all possible combinations first and than filters out those you that you want to include.